# Downloading a file with a wildcard from Sharepoint URL with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, excel, sharepoint, vba

I'm not sure if this can be done or not but I thought I'd ask!

I'm running a windows 10 PC using Python 2.7. I'm wanting to download a file form sharepoint to a folder on my C: drive.

```
OpenPath = "https://office.test.com/sites/Rollers/New improved files/"
OpenFile = "ABC UK.xlsb"
```

The downside is the file is uploaded externally & due to human error it can be saved as a .xlsx or ABC_UK. Therefor I only want to use the first 3 characters with a wildcard (ABC*) to open that file. Thankfully the first 3 Characters are unique & there only be one file in the path that should match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to find the file in your dir:

```
import os, requests, fnmatch
#loop over dir
for filename in os.listdir(OpenPath):
    #find the file
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, 'ABC_UK*'):
        #download the file
        # open file handler
        with open('C:\dwnlfile.xls', 'wb') as fh:
            #try to get it 
            result = requests.get(OpenPath+filename)
            #check u got it
            if not result.ok:
                print result.reason # or text
                exit(1)
            #save it 

            fh.write(result.content)
            print 'got it and saved'
```

Comment: Looks good, but I'm getting an error
(***'return' outside fuction)

Comment: so put it in a function or replace the return with "print 'exit byebye'"

Comment: Also no module named request.

Comment: pip install requests

Comment: My work PC does not allow the PIP Connection.... Gutted. I'll need to find another way. Thank you

Comment: Ok, it looks like it's running but I'm now getting print error 'Unauthorised'

Comment: Thanks, U c the auth error  because we printed the error reason, the server, office.test.com, wants user and password, look at requests package docs to c how to send them, it is easy